# One thread can change the reference to the array while another thread is iterating through it

Tags: c#, arrays, multithreading

I have a static array variable which is being shared by two threads.

I'd like to understand what happens if I assign the array variable to another array object in `Thread1` while `Thread2` is iterating over the array.

I.e

In thread 1

```
MyStaticClass.MyArray = SomeOtherArray
```

While in Thread 2:

```
for (int i = 0; i < MyStaticClass.MyArray.length; i++) 
{ 
    //do something with the i'th element
}
```

Comment: The result isn't easily predictable. It may continue iterating fine (though obviously swapping the variable you're using in the middle of a loop is probably *bad*). It may crash if you are trying to use an index that is now greater than the array length. This type of code would be very bad form, and is the reason locks were invented. In general, the best rule of thumbs for multi-threading are to avoid sharing data between threads, and always lock what you do share.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming `MyStaticClass.MyArray` is just a field or simple property.

Nothing good or predictable will happen that's for sure.

I'd say most likely are:

- The loop may read one half of old array and rest from new array
- The new array may be shorter than the last giving a exception when you access `[i]`
- **Or** Thread 2 may actually completely ignore the change to the array! And what's worse, this behaviour may be different in Release build to Debug.

The last situation is due to compiler optimisations and/or the way the memory model works in .net (and other languages like Java BTW). There's a whole keyword to get around this issue (`volatile`) http://igoro.com/archive/volatile-keyword-in-c-memory-model-explained/

Answer (score 1):

To prevent this, you want to use a lock to lock the critical section.  Basically wrapping your itteration in a lock will prevent the other thread from overwriting the array while you are processing it

> The lock keyword ensures that one thread does not enter a critical section of code while another thread is in the critical section. If another thread tries to enter a locked code, it will wait, block, until the object is released.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c5kehkcz.aspx

Answer (score 1):

The condition in your `for` loop is evaluated for every iteration. So if another thread changes the reference in `MyStaticClass.MyArray`, you use this new reference in the next iteration.

For example, this code:

```
int[] a = {1,2,3,4,5};
int[] b =  {10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70};

for (int i = 0; i < a.Length; i++)
{
     Console.WriteLine(a[i]);
     a = b;
}
```

gives this output:

```
1
20
30
40
50
60
70
```

To avoid this, you could use `foreach`:

```
foreach(int c in a)
{
    Console.WriteLine(c);
    a = b;
}
```

gives:

```
1
2
3
4
5
```

because `foreach` is translated so that it calls `a.GetEnumerator()` once and then uses this enumerator (`MoveNext()` and `Current`) for all iterations, not accessing `a` again.

Comment: Hmm is one complete atomic iteration guaranteed before the swap will take place? Since you're iterating in a single thread its executing sequentially. This might not be true in my case.

Comment: @user2635088 No (though I don't know what an _atomic_ iteration could be). If the other thread changes `MyArray` right after the iterating thread leaves the `for` line, then inside the loop you are already accessing the new array reference. This may already lead to an `IndexOutOfRangeException` if the new array is smaller than your current index `i`.

Comment: @user2635088 I just used a single-thread example for simplicity. I only wanted to show that the `for` loop is evaluating `MyArray` every time it accesses this variable and does not _cache_ it away. So you should avoid changing it in another thread while iterating.

Answer (score 0):

There will be no consequences other than thread 2 at some point starting to work on the new array instead of the old. When exactly this happens is more or less random, and as weston writes in his comment, it may never even happen at all.

If the new array has fewer elements than the old one this can (but doesn't have to) cause a runtime exception.

Comment: You can't guarantee Thread 2 will *ever* work on the new array. Read this about the memory model in .net http://igoro.com/archive/volatile-keyword-in-c-memory-model-explained/